# how to perform sort on array of luxon objects

Tags: javascript, sorting, luxon

I am trying to use js sort of luxon time objects. I am not sure if this is correct as sort expects `-1,0,1`

```
const results  = objectGroupedByYearMonth[year][month].results.sort(
          (a,b) => 
            DateTime.fromISO(b.created)
              .diff(DateTime.fromISO(a.created))
        )
```

This returns a dt object `console.log("DIF: ", DateTime.fromISO("2020-11-03T17:01:22.205041Z") .diff(DateTime.fromISO("2020-11-03T17:15:23.998284Z")))`

Answer (score 12):

You might want to [convert](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/formatting#unix-timestamps) the `DateTime` objects to numerical Unix timestamps:

```ts
function compareLuxonDates(a: DateTime, b: DateTime) {
  return a.toMillis() - b.toMillis()
}
arrayWithDateObjects.sort(compareLuxonDates)
```

Answer (score 7):

[According to their docs](https://moment.github.io/luxon/docs/manual/math.html#comparing-datetimes), Luxon's `DateTime` class implements `#valueof`, which returns the primitive value of an object– in this case it's the epoch milliseconds. That means you can directly use `<` or `>` to compare Luxon DateTime objects when sorting.

Here's a one-liner `compareFn` I use to sort Luxon DateTime arrays sometimes.

### The quick answer

```js
sortDateTimes = (a, b) => a < b ? -1 : a > b ? 1 : 0;
```

This approach works because equality is the catch-all condition (the `0` at the end). Although you can use `<` and `>` freely with `DateTime` objects, you **can't** just use `===` to check for equality. Luxon provides a `.equals(...)` function for that. Alternative, because they implement `#valueOf`, you can make the `DateTime` objects convert to their primitive values using `+`.

```js
const { DateTime } = require('luxon');

a = DateTime.fromISO('2020-01-15');
b = DateTime.fromISO('2020-01-15');

a === b; // false
+a === +b; // true
```

The little `compareFn` one-liner above works fine on an array of `DateTime` objects, but since we often want to sort an array of objects that the `DateTime` embedded in a property (like `created`), we have to take a slightly different approach.

```js
sortByCreated = (a, b) =>  
  a.created < b.created ? -1 : a.created > b.created ? 1 : 0;
```

### The robust answer

For bonus points, make this a little more reusable with a function generator.

```js
createPropertySorter = (propertyName) => (a, b) =>
  a[propertyName] < b[propertyName] ? -1 : a[propertyName] > b[propertyName] ? 1 : 0;
```

The generator would then be used when you need to sort instead of the sort function itself directly. From OP's example:

```js
const results = objectGroupedByYearMonth[year][month].results.sort(
    createPropertySorter('created')
  );

// results is now sorted, e.g. results.map(JSON.stringify) is
// [
//  '{"name":"some Object","created":"2020-01-25T00:00:00.000-07:00"}',
//  '{"name":"some Object","created":"2020-01-31T00:00:00.000-07:00"}',
//  '{"name":"some Object","created":"2020-02-01T00:00:00.000-07:00"}',
//  '{"name":"some Object","created":"2020-02-01T00:00:00.000-07:00"}',
//  '{"name":"some Object","created":"2020-02-07T00:00:00.000-07:00"}'
// ]
```

#### Watch out for mutability

A quick aside on mutability: in the example above, `objectGroupedByYearMonth[year][month]` has a property called `results`. Because `sort()` sorts arrays *in-place*, `objectGroupedByYearMonth[year][month].results` is *also* sorted (not just the returned value). This may have been the OP's intention, or it may be inconsequential, but I think it's worth minding. A revised version that preserves the original sorting would sort a *copy* of the original array using the spread operator.

```js
const results = [...objectGroupedByYearMonth[year][month].results].sort(
    createPropertySorter('created')
  );
// results is sorted, while objectGroupedByYearMonth[year][month].results
// is still in its original order
```

#### Reverse sorting

If you want to reverse the sort order (latest dates first), switch `a` and `b` in the sort function.

```js
createPropertyReverseSorter = (propertyName) => (a, b) =>
  b[propertyName] < a[propertyName] ? -1 : b[propertyName] > a[propertyName] ? 1 : 0;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could take the string directly for comparison with [`String#localeCompare`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/localeCompare).

```
(a, b) => b.created.localeCompare(a.created)
```

Comment: So if I wanted asc or desc I would just reverse and `b` and `a`

Comment: @shorif2000 Yes, if you want to reverse, you just switch those 2